# Как сравнить две даты с учетом времени Y-m-d H:i:s

Tags: php, дата, datetime, время

Есть дата и время формата 2021-08-30 01:15:00, как можно сравнить ее с текущей date("Y-m-d H:i:s") в php?

Comment: что значит "сравнить"?

Comment: проверить, текущая дата и время date("Y-m-d H:i:s") больше или меньше заданной 2021-08-30 01:15:00, т.е. наступило ли событие или нет

Comment: самое простое использовать strtotime

Comment: продвинутей - использовать diff https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php

Comment: можно сравнить просто два DateTime обычным знаком > < = (`$d1 = new DateTime('2008-08-03 14:52:10');
$d2 = new DateTime('2008-01-03 11:11:10');`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11 12:12:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13 10:12:00');

if ($datetime1 > $datetime2) {
    echo 'datetime1 greater than datetime2';
}

if ($datetime1 < $datetime2) {
    echo 'datetime1 lesser than datetime2';
}

if ($datetime1 == $datetime2) {
    echo 'datetime2 is equal than datetime1';
}
```

Второй:

```
$datetime1 = strtotime('2009-10-11 12:12:00');
$datetime2 = strtotime('2009-10-13 10:12:00');

if ($datetime1 > $datetime2) {
    echo 'datetime1 greater than datetime2';
}

if ($datetime1 < $datetime2) {
    echo 'datetime1 lesser than datetime2';
}

if ($datetime1 == $datetime2) {
    echo 'datetime2 is equal than datetime1';
}
```

Comment: а что, просто написать  `if ('2021-08-30 01:15:00' > date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))` нельзя было?

Comment: да можно, сам накосячил со знаками...

Comment: @ChikChirik ну и зачем плодить очередной дубликат на сайте? Как будто мало тут мусора

Comment: для кого-то мусор, для кого-то решение

Comment: @ChikChirik сиюминутное решение для проблемы, которая уже была решена 100500 раз, и очередное кривое "решение" только замусоривает сайт. **Не надо думать только о себе**